# Приложение без activity

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Требуется сделать приложение которое просто работало бы в фоне, у которого нет "окна" "активити". Использую такую цепочку BroadcastReceiver -> WakefulBroadcastReceiver -> Service

Вот такой манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.test.application"
android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application>
    <receiver
        android:name=".StartClass" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <receiver
        android:name=".SyncNewsAlarm" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
    </receiver>

    <service android:name=".ServerSyns"></service>
</application>
```

С разных статей напихал всего чего можно, но все равно вообще ничего не происходит. Вернее не запускается. В Android Studio -> Run -> Edit Configurations -> Launch Options -> Поставил Nothing (Ибо если оставить стандартное Default Activity) то будет ошибка Default Activity not found.

Класс .StartClass

```
public class StartClass extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED")) {

            SyncNewsAlarm syncNewsAlarm = new SyncNewsAlarm();
            syncNewsAlarm.setAlarm(context);
        }
    }
}
```

Подскажите как реализовать.